# Carrierwave; Saving Image on Production server and moving them?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

EDIT: **My files are only stored as stated by cache and not by store_dir**

I have spent hours trying to get this to work, Carrierwave works as it should locally, but on my production they only get saved in Cache_dir and the form is not redirecting me to my specified path.

Is it neccessary to Move the file from it's released TMP-folder to where it should be? Or shouldnt carrierwave do this automatically?

Posting a lot of Code if someone wants to help.

My file gets saved @:

```
/releases/20150601122454/public/uploads/tmp/pics/1433164111-29887-8666/elg.jpg
```

And I am trying to move it with:

```
require 'fileutils'
   tmp = params[:instruction][:image].tempfile
   newfile = File.join("public/system/pics",params[:instruction][:image].original_filename)
  FileUtils.touch('newfile') 
  FileUtils.copy_file(tmp.path,newfile)
```

This only crashes saying

> No such file or directory - public/system/pics/elg.jpg

Her is my Image_Uploader:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog




  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
 def store_dir
    "system/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def cache_dir
    "uploads/tmp/pics"
  end
```

Here is how I update my model:

```
def update
    file = params[:instruction][:image]
   puts @instruction.text + " HERE IT IS " +file.path
   @instruction.image = file
   @instruction.save
   Rails.logger.info("@inst.image path: " + @instruction.image.path)

  require 'fileutils'
  # tmp = params[:instruction][:image].tempfile
  # newfile = File.join("public/system/pics",params[:instruction][:image].original_filename)
   #FileUtils.touch('newfile') 
   #FileUtils.copy_file(tmp.path,newfile)

    if @instruction.update(instruction_params)
      redirect_to instructions_path, notice: 'Instruktionerna sparades.'
    else
     render action: 'edit' , alert: 'Misslyckades att uppdatera instruktionerna'
    end
```

end

```
 def instruction_params
    params.require(:instruction).permit(:text,:role_id)
end
```

My Form:

```
<%= form_for @instruction, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
    <br>
    <div> 
    <%= f.file_field :image%>

    <%= f.hidden_field :image_cache %>
    </div>
    <br>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.text_area :text, rows: 15, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit 'Spara', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The model:

```
class Instruction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Please please, I really need help.

Comment: Everything works like a charm on my local computer, but in my servern which is deployed through Capistrano it only saved the image in a TMP folder....

Answer (score 1):

**Possible approach #1** - add a `/#{Rails.root}/public`

```
File.join("/#{Rails.root}/public/system/pics",params[:instruction][:image].original_filename)
```

**Possible approach #2**

> Verify that Rails has permission to read/write to your file system.

**Reference similar to the code I have running in production atm**

This is *similar* to the code we have in production which works, well.

```
class SomeUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  ...

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    if Rails.env.production?
      "uploads/prod/#{model.id}"
    else if Rails.env.staging?
      "uploads/staging/#{model.id}"
    else
      "uploads/dev/#{model.id}"
    end
  end
```

Comment: How do I check if Rails has permission?

Comment: Do I need to Create the file before doing a file_copy och move with FileUtils?

Comment: Carrierwave should write to a a new file path if it has permission. You shouldn't need to a create a new file. Try creating a new file/folder with rails and see if you are able to first. If not, chances are that is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to overwrite the store_dir:

**The following Snippets belongs to the carrier wave documentation:**

### Changing the storage directory

In order to change where uploaded files are put, just override the store_dir method:

```
# Configure carrierwave root directory 
# config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.root = Rails.root
end

# Overwrite store dir 
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def store_dir
    'public/my/upload/directory'
  end
end
```

This works for the file storage as well as Amazon S3 and Rackspace Cloud Files. Define store_dir as nil if you'd like to store files at the root level.

If you store files outside the project root folder, you may want to define cache_dir in the same way:

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def cache_dir
    '/tmp/projectname-cache'
  end
end
```

Comment: Hmm, yes I tried this and I think the problem resides in the fact that it is only stored in a TMP and not as stated by the  store_dir

Comment: I changed it to

 def store_dir
    "system/uploads/images"
  end


But it doesnt change anything, it only gets saved where i specified my 

  def cache_dir
    "system/uploads/tmp/images"
  end

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing this dirty trick:

```
require 'fileutils'
  tmp = @instruction.image
  newfile =  File.join("/#{Rails.root}/public/system/pics",params[:instruction][:image].original_filename)

   if File.exists?(newfile)
      else
      FileUtils.makedirs("/#{Rails.root}/public/system/pics")
   end
   FileUtils.mv(tmp.path,newfile)
   @instruction.image = File.open(newfile)
   @instruction.save
```

Answer (score 0):

Spent a lot of hours today for the same problem: CarrierWave save only tmp files on server (uploads/tmp folder with original names) and don't save records to DB (just BEGIN ROLLBACK). 
Solution was so elementary: to install imagemagick on my server - i forgot about it :)